# I performed an experiment similar to see if switching really works in the monty hall problem, It didn't.

Tags: probability, monty-hall

I recently learnt about the Monty Hall problem. Theory says you should always switch since probability of winning then is twice. But I feel why won't probability be redistributed and be half for each door..once one door has been opened.
So I performed an experiment. I was Monty and my sister had to choose. We did 18 rounds and the result was shockingly surprising. 2 times out of 9, switching won the car, 7 times it failed, and amazingly, 2 times out of 9, not switching won the car and it too failed 7 times. Is there something very convincing in favor of switching?

Comment: It's just a coincidence. Try doing the experiment $1000$ times and see if the results are more convincing ;-) Also note that the theory only gives a $2/3$ probability, which will be hard to distinguish from $1/2$ with a low number of samples. I won't do the statistical computations, but I would be surprised if your result is statistically significant.

Comment: $2$ successes or fewer out of $7$ is unlikely for a $1/2$ chance (less than $10\%$ probability) and very unlikely for a $2/3$ chance (less than $1\%$ probability). Having such lopsided results **twice** for a $1/2$ chance is also highly unlikely. (The observed "not switching" results are relatively consistent with the $2/3$ case.) It seems you're either experiencing the phenomenon that freak occurrences sometimes occur (every once in a while, a fair coin comes up heads ten times in a row), or there's something wrong with your procedure.

Comment: See if you are correctly following the rules. The host most know the locations of the contents and so deliberately always remove a wrong option from the two that the player did not pick. I have seen many people that make the mistake of randomly discarding an option, and if it results to be which has the prize, they don't count the game and repeat it. That changes the proportions, although which you got would still be very unlikely.

Comment: @Milten To seperate the probabilities 1/2 and 2/3 , a quite low sample is usually sufficient, $100$ however can still be too low, $300$ almost surely works. We have of course never absolutely certainess. I think that the game simply was wrong simulated.